# Show a transparent activity above the lock screen such that the lock screen still is visible

Tags: android, keyguard

I have an activity which pops up everywhere (when a specific GCM message is received). Since the activity has a transparent area you still can see everything through it, depending on where you are on your Android device. It is also shown above the PIN-lock screen for example. I achieve this by starting the activity with the transparent layout by:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
        // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

The problem is that in that case the transparent area of the activity get grey only. You cannot see the lock screen through it. Is there a way to start that activity above the lock screen, such that the lock screen remains visible?

Comment: use a fragment with no background color specified. It basically will provide a fully transparent view on top. If you dont want to allow clicks through it, set android:clickable=true. Or set android:background="@android:color/transparent" in your activitiy's root layout

Comment: That was not what I was asking for. Of course I built a transparent activity. Its just not working that you see the lock screen through it, but everything else works.

Comment: Het @softwaresupply did you find solution for this scenario?